# URL Preview not showing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp

When I copy and Paste my Website link on Whatsapp it doesn't preview it.

My Website ink is: https://flashyupdates.ml

I am using wp optimise plugin and already tried disabling inline css option but problem is still there also tried disabling plugin.